# Wrong time but the date is fine

Tags: php, mysql

Wrong Time zone , but to insert into the db i used now();

Comment: Please provide the code you're using

Comment: check server/s timezone settings. Also check timezone settings for your php script

Comment: check the timezone on the server

Answer (score 3):

PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method works with whatever timezone is set. To set the timezone, use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

From the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) docs:

> Every call to a date/time function will generate a `E_NOTICE` if the time zone is not valid, and/or a `E_STRICT` or `E_WARNING` message if using the system settings or the TZ environment variable. See also [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Here's the [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

---

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $date;
```

---

You should note that PHP will only use the time set on the computer it's running on. It will not use a client's local time.

MySQL will use the system time and whichever timezone is set in the mysql configuration. To set the timezone in MySQL, use

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

For more information, see [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) sys var docs.

Comment: ok thanks but now I wanna do it for South Africa Johannesburg not America /Chicago coz the client is in Johannesburg

Comment: I already provided a list for the supported timezones. I also update my post to use the `Africa/Johannesburg` timezone setting.

Comment: I checked there thanks And I got pretily well but now to inser it into the db its giving me a problem but be4 i was Inserting it like now()

Comment: Don't say "It's giving me a problem" but "It's giving me *this* problem", followed by the error, or a description of what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks Man I managed to fix it I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The time of you system may be different than the server time. That is because your server might be in different location & it's time zone may be different.

you can set timezone by

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
```

Comment: It is helpful stating what 'may' be wrong, but you have not actually offered a way to fix it. I suggest you edit your answer so that it is actually an answer

Comment: @BenCarey Soory about that & thanks for suggetions